# jQuery fadeOut callback doesn't trigger... Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, fadeout

here is the code I am using, the call back on 'animate' in the mouseenter event works, but the callback on the fade out doesn't. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$('#about-me .progress-bar .progress .notes li').live('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).animate({
        top:25
    },function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
    });     
}).live('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find('.caption').stop(true, true).delay(400).fadeOut(400,function(){
        $(this).animate({
            top:40
        });         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to animate the .caption that you just faded? I would suspect not but this is what your function is doing. Try changing:

```
$(this).animate({
            top:40
        });
```

to

```
$(this).parents('li').animate({
            top:40
        });
```

*I am assuming there is only one li above the caption here*

Comment: Ahh damn. Sometimes you just get so close to what you're writing you miss something stupid like that. For some reason I still thought the element in focus was already the li. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> .fadeOut( [ duration ], [ callback ] )
>
> callback:   A function to call once the
>   animation is complete.

as you can see, the callback will be called when `fadeOut` is complete, which means that you can't see the element, then how could you see if the animate on its `top` property is working or not? maybe you should use `console.log("something")` in the callback function to see if it is reachable.